# install vite on laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, vite, laravel-mix

I want to install Vite in my Laravel 8 project. What should I do to migrate from Laravel Mix to Vite?

I have followed another tutorial on the web, but it didn't work for me

1. Install Vite and the Laravel Plugin
   `npm install --save-dev vite laravel-vite-plugin`
2. Configure Vite

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel([
            'resources/css/app.css',
            'resources/js/app.js',
        ]),
    ],
});
```

3. Update NPM

```
"scripts": {
-     "dev": "npm run development",
-     "development": "mix",
-     "watch": "mix watch",
-     "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
-     "hot": "mix watch --hot",
-     "prod": "npm run production",
-     "production": "mix --production"
+     "dev": "vite",
+     "build": "vite build"
  }
```

and another step on https://balajidharma.medium.com/how-to-migrating-from-laravel-mix-to-vite-fbb912237844

Comment: Do your layout files still reference `mix`? They should reference `@vite`

Comment: @waterloomatt yes, because it's old laravel version, laravel 8

Comment: check this v0.2.4 of mix-to-vite [here](https://github.com/laravel/vite-plugin/blob/v0.2.4/UPGRADE.md)

Comment: Were you able to configure Vite in Laravel 8 project? I think it requires Laravel 9 and above.